# Phonegap : FileTransfer.upload() on android gives OOM error for big files

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova, file-transfer

i am using phonegap 1.3 to develop an android app. android verison - 2.3.3

I am using FileTransfer.upload() to upload a video files to the server. My code works for small files but for big ones(more that 3-4 Mb) it gives OOM. My

```
options.chunkedMode = true;
```

Here are the logs from my device for the out of memory while uploading the file. Please help me figure out whats going wrong with Phonegap.

[image: The logs for OOM in android logcat]

**EDIT:** This happens only in Android 2.3.3. It works fine in Android 3.0 and above.

Comment: have you got any fix on this ?